# How to print a column of a matrix(2D list) in python without a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

To print the 2nd row I do like this
`print(coeff_matrix[2])`

to my surprise
`print(coeff_matrix[:][2])`
prints the 2nd row as well , not the 2nd column as I was expecting.
Why is it so and what is the correct way to print 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert coefficient_matrix to a numpy array and use slicing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8, 9]])
a[:,1]
```

Output:

```
array([2, 5, 8])
```

If numpy is not available, you can use `zip`:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8, 9]]
list(zip(*a))[1]
```

Output:

```
(2, 5, 8)
```

Or list comprehension (if that counts as without a loop?):

```
[i[1] for i in a]
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 8]
```

If you also want to set values, you can use `zip` twice:

```
a = [[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7,8, 9]]
a = list(zip(*a))
a[1] = (69, 69, 69)
list(zip(*a))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 69, 3), (4, 69, 6), (7, 69, 9)]
```

Comment: I dont have the luxury to use numpy. if possible suggest a native way.

Comment: @BobMcCheese Edited to include ways that don't use numpy

Comment: Actually now I have another problem, I not just want to print, but also to update the 2nd column with values from a linear list. Maybe I should post that as a separate question.

Comment: @BobMcCheese edited for if you want to set values in a

Comment: Thanks. Now I feel loops would have been simpler. Anyways nevermind, thanks for the prompt reply.